# Loading into SQL database using K8s - duplicate data?

Tags: sql, kubernetes

this question is more conceptual rather than code based.
I am using Kubernetes to orchestrate a scheduled data-upload into a SQL Server.
K8s is relatively new to me and I was wondering how I prevent the same data from being uploaded twice when I have multiple pods running looking to upload new data.

Is this something that I need to work out within the image(s) I allocate to each Pod?

Comment: I suggest to not use multiple replicas for such a job.

Comment: I pretty much agree with your final question. The pod itself can write to some external storage to be able to resume when restarted, or multiple pods can somehow coordinate who's writing what data. Or the insert code can do some idempotent upsert operation if possible. Possibly you want to use k8s jobs but the pods still need something for failure case.